# How does mathematica handle roots of complex numbers

Tags: complex

When Mathematica takes  $(-1)^{\frac{3}{4}}$, is it really interpreting it as $((-1)^3)^{\frac{1}{4}}$, or $((-1)^{\frac{1}{4}})^3$?

These seem like they would give $e^{i \frac{3\pi}{4}}$ versus $\left((e^{i \frac{\pi}{4}}) \cdot (\text{fourth root of unity}) \right)$

And the following makes me a little confused.

```
Simplify[(-1)^(3/4)  Sqrt[I a], a \[Element] Reals]
Simplify[(-1)^(3/4)  Sqrt[I a], a > 0]
Simplify[(-1)^(3/4)  Sqrt[I a], a < 0]
```

Returns:

```
(-1)^(3/4) Sqrt[I a]
-Sqrt[a]
(-1)^(3/4) Sqrt[I a]
```

How does Mathematica produce these results?

Comment: (-1)^(3/4) is defined as ((-1)^(1/4))^3. For that second simplification, a>0 allows to pull it out of the sqrt. Then sqrt(I) is (-1)^(1/4) and summing powers of -1 gives the final result of -sqrt(a).

Comment: @DanielLichtblau, then if a is negative, why can't it pull -a out of the square root?

Comment: Mathematically one could get `I*Sqrt[-a]`. `Simplify` does not manage to find that. `FullSimplify` does give that result. `In[128]:= FullSimplify[(-1)^(3/4)   Sqrt[I  a], a < 0]

Out[128]= I Sqrt[-a]`